# How to convert a Type_Byte_Binary BufferedImage with Alpha to an TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Im using the code

```
BufferedImage imgIn = ImageIO.read(is);

    BufferedImage image;
    if (imgIn.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED) {
        image = new BufferedImage(imgIn.getWidth(), imgIn.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        ColorConvertOp cco = new ColorConvertOp(imgIn.getColorModel()
                .getColorSpace(), image.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), null);
        cco.filter(imgIn, image);
    } else {
        image = imgIn;
    }
```

When I'm pulling in an image with a Bit Depth of 4 it makes the imgIn a Type_Byte_Binary. When It gets converted to Type_4Byte_ABGR anything with partial transparency changes color and loses all alpha. Fully transparent pixels and Fully Opaque pixels remained unchanged.

Is there anything I can do to keep the partially transparent pixels from changing?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce this (without an example image), but can't you just paint the source image into the graphics of the target image (hoping that the conversion of the colors is then done properly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `ColorConvertOp` isn't what you are after here, because the images are all in RGB (sRGB) color space (`IndexColorModel` doesn't support other color spaces).

Instead, just paint your `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` or `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` onto a `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR` image, and any transparency should be preserved.

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imgIn.getWidth(), imgIn.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

Grphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

try {
    g.drawImage(imgIn, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```